# springboot resources FileNotFoundException

Tags: spring-boot

I've deployed a SpringBoot project and I got FileNotFoundException even though it runs totally fine on local.

Here is the code:

(1)

```
   Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("file/");

   File file = resource.getFile();
```

(2)

```
   File fileDir = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:file");
```

Here is the error:

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [file/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app/myspringboot/jar/my-spring-boot-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/file/

    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:217)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:154)
    at com.test.controller.TestController.test1(TestController.java:50)
    at com.test.controller.TestController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$121d66f5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.test.file.controller.TestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bda4cbc8.test1(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Maven Structure

```
    src
       main
           resources
                   file
                       test1.txt
                       test2.txt
                       test3.txt
```

Question:

I'm not sure how many files are in the resources/file directory,so I want to get to the directory first and then iterate over it。
Neither of the above methods is acceptable。
What should I do?

Comment: Those aren't files as those are part of the jar. A file is a physical resource on your filesystem **not** something that is packaged into a jar/war/ear (hence it works locally as that runs unpacked).

Comment: I know, InputStream ways can get?

Comment: Use `getInputStream` instead of `getFile`.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much